# Save annotated PDF notes as plain text from Preview

Tags: macos, pdf, preview.app

I have several PDFs with notes attached to them using the annotation toolbar in Preview on OS X. Is there a way to extract all notes from a PDF file into a text file?

[Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) does this really well, but it uses a proprietary notes format that doesn't work in Preview or Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert Notes via [Skim](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io/) does the job for me. Just load the annotated PDF into Skim, convert and you can now export the notes as regular Skim notes.

[image: image description here]

Comment: Ooh. That's perfect! I had no idea "Convert Notes…" existed. Thanks!